# Intercept button on bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

I am trying to intercept the only one button on a bluetooth headset. I have tried many things found on the site but none worked. The main activivity manages the bluetooth connection (using a code from https://github.com/sauravpradhan/AnySound2BT).

I have the following manifest file :

```
...
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>


        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
...
```

When I click once, nothing happens and the second time the phone asks me to start "S voice" or "Google appli".

Thanks for any hint

Karim

Answer (score 0):

Their are many methods to intercept the button function if this button really did something.

According to your description, the phone asks you to start "S voice" or "Google appli" then I assume one of the button's combined function is "Voice Recognition Activation".

You can export the btsnoop log of the Android, then click the HFP tab, to find out the AT command, then you can understand what the button sends.

Note that for all of the button on the headset, the long press,short press, and continue short press, the the press during calling or not calling,might have different meaning.